# pop3s connection failure - javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException - EOF on socket

Tags: apache-nifi, pop3

I want to read an email using **pop3s** protocol in nifi.

Currently nifi  has a **pop3** email consumer does not have an option to specify to use **pop3s**.

When I use this processor, I am getting the below error.

I searched for the error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53724265/javamail-authenticationfailedexception-eof-on-socket/53725541) where it says that I should **pop3s** protocol.

I have a java application which uses **pop3s** protocol and was able to read the email.

[image]

Can some one advise me how to configure **pop3s** in NiFi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding,
the below attributes, the pop3s protocol is automatically achieved.

> mail.debug  - true
> mail.pop3.socketFactory.class - mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback
> javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory - false

[image: Nifi Configuration]